# Celery v4 not routing tasks as expected

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm updating my celery workers from celery v3 to celery v4, and all my tasks are ***Class Based Tasks***. [I have manually registered the tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.0/whatsnew-4.0.html#the-task-base-class-no-longer-automatically-register-tasks) since it's what indicated in the upgrade doc.

The problem is in task routing, I have the following *Task*:

```
class RegisterTask(Task):
    routing_key = 'app_server.register'

    def run(**params):
        whatever ...
```

I'm running two celery workers, one on the default queue, and the other on the register queue, like below:

```
# Default Worker
celery -A app_server worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=1

# Register Worker
celery -A app_server worker -Q app_server_register --loglevel=info --concurrency=1
```

and here's my queues definition:

```
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'app_server_default'
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'app_server.default'

CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
    Queue('app_server_default', routing_key='app_server.default'),
    Queue('app_server_register', routing_key='app_server.register')
)
```

The unexpected behavior is the difference I see when I call the task using Celery V3 and Celery V4.

```
# Celery V3
RegisterTask().delay(**params)
# task is consumed by the register worker!

# Celery V4
RegisterTask().delay(**params)
# task is consumed by the default worker!
```

And I want the task to be consumed by the *register worker* (celery v3 behavior), hence why I hardcoded the **routing_key** attribute in the class based task. But Celery V4 seems to ignore the *routing_key* attribute in the class based task.

[I'm also using *redis* as the broker, if it's any important]

Any Ideas on this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`routing_key` as a class attribute is deprecated in v4.

You can supply it to a task on invocation as
a kwarg to  `apply_async` or you can manually configure routing task types to queues in celery config.
See the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing)

---

The Task class at `celery.task.base.Task` is deprecated for `celery.app.task.Task`.

This is a design change where the new Task class prefers to bind configuration when the task is used as opposed to at instantiation time.
See [this comment](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/e257646136e6fae73186d7385317f4e20cd36130/celery/app/task.py#L319-L320)

Looking through the source you can see `routing_key` is set when the task is bound using `_get_exec_options`. [Here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/e257646136e6fae73186d7385317f4e20cd36130/celery/app/task.py#L1016-L1019) the options are set using an instance (`self`) not the class.

I've gathered this by looking at the celery source code but if there's no mention of deprecation in the docs I guess they're out of date.

Perhaps filling an issue on their github and using one of the options provided in the new paradigm is the best option going forward.

---

> Also there's in the doc that tasks routing_key will be read from task metadata, so class based tasks can't have this metadata anymore?

Correct, the metadata isn't on the class object anymore. It is set via config or lazily via a task instance when called.

The config file should be the goto for static routing while setting on task call should be used for overriding the configured default.

Comment: I can't find a doc indicating it's deprecated. And the behavior seems like "deleted" to me, not deprecated. Can you please guide me to a doc/discussion anything that indicates it's now not supported and the reasons why? I'm particularly interested in knowing what now happens to celery 3.1.25 workers calling tasks of v4 workers, they will all need to be re-written to explicitly indicate the routing_key, or will end up in the default queue? Also there's in the doc that tasks routing_key will be read from task metadata, so class based tasks can't have this metadata anymore?

Comment: RE: tasks ending up in the default queue, you can configure queues to auto-create for tasks see: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_create_missing_queues

Comment: Thanks for taking the time :) the `_get_exec_options` seems to get attributes from the self object on invocation, and routing_key when set as a static variable, should be accessible as an attribute on any `self` object, so I don't see why it shouldn't work. Also one other thing is that I've tried writing a custom `task_router` function, and explicitly returning the routing_key but still wouldn't work. On the other hand, explicitly returning {"queue": "app_server_register"} from the task_router function works and the task is redirected to the right queue. Can't understand why though :(